# XRegExp: negate expression

Tags: regex, unicode, xregexp

What is the negate expression of following [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) expression?

```
[\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Nd}\\{Pc}\\p{M}]+
```

I used `matchChain()` to get the words out of the sentence using above expression.

Now I'm going to use `split()` using negate expression to get the same result but with containing delimiters for each words.

Comment: Add `^` at the beginning of your character class?

Answer (score 2):

To negate `\p{…}`, use `\P{…}`. For example, the inverse of `\p{L}` is `\P{L}`.

Assuming you made a typo in your original regular expression, and `\\{Pc}` should be `\\p{Pc}`, this becomes:

```
[\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Nd}\\p{Pc}\\p{M}]+
```

To negate this, just uppercase `\\p{…}` into `\\P{…}`:

```
[\\P{Alphabetic}\\P{Nd}\\P{Pc}\\P{M}]+
```

It should be possible to just do this as well:

```
[^\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Nd}\\p{Pc}\\p{M}]+
```

Comment: the negation inside the square brackets seems wrong to me: it matches anything!

Answer (score 0):

To negate a character class you can add a `^` at the beginning of the class, so in your example

```
[^\\p{Alphabetic}\\p{Nd}\\p{Pc}\\p{M}]+
```

Note that `\p{…}` can be negated as `\P{…}` but it has some pitfalls:

```
[^\\p{Nd}] is the same of [\\P{Nd}]
```

but

```
[\\P{Nd}\\P{Pc}] // wrong
```

will match anything! because a number (Nd) is absolutely a non punctuation (Pc)